# Is There Real Global Parameters in Flink Streaming?

Tags: apache-flink

Is there real global parameters that all paralleled tasks(whichever TM they are running on) can write and read? I tested GlobalJobParameter Class, but it seems that each thread maintain its own instance. I'm looking for some place that all UDFs can share. Does anyone know? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GlobalJobParameter` is a read-only distribution to configure a job. As you mentioned "**write** and read" I guess you are looking for a global shared state. Flink does not support something like this, because a global shared state does **not scale**, and contradicts the idea of data parallelism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!